# Add parameters based on environment variable in JENKINS?

Tags: jenkins, parameters, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the "Exports Parameters Plugin" in Jenkins. I use it to export my different Build parameters into a JSON file. I can export my parameters that's not the problem but I would like to export environnement variable as well...

Is that possible to use environment variable as a KEY in the plugin or to define a parameter based on a environment variable ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin in the following way :

Run an execute shell step

`echo Variable_Name=$(echo variable_name) > tempfile`

Run **Inject environment variables** build step from the plugin and give the path of this tempfile in the Properties File Path.

The tempfile should have somethign like this 
`Variable_Name=variable_name`

Another method using the same plugin is to inject the variable right at the startup under the "Properties Content".

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: You use environment variables like
`echo ${Build_Number}`

Comment: Hi thks but it doesn't work. :( my "tempfile" contains the "Build_ID=106", I add the path to the build step "Inject environment variables" but then when I try to use "Build_ID" as a parameter...nothing is printing...I think "Build_ID" is a environment variables and not a parameter.

Comment: I tried with the "Properties Content", but it doesn't work as well.